# Add a month of padding from minimum date

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

First I want to dynamically handle the range of dates for any kind of temporal data set. This I achieved using:

```
var earliest = d3.min(data.map(d=>d.date));
var latest = d3.max(data.map(d=>d.date));
```

Then I want to add a month of padding so the data don't look so precarious hanging on the edges. So I tried:

```
var dateMin = earliest;
var dateMax = latest;

dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getMonth()-30);
dateMax.setDate(dateMax.getMonth()+30);
```

It seems that the scale still remembers the initial `earliest` value, even though I copied it. That is to say, all this ended up doing was literally change my data point to be an earlier date, meaning that the result is unchanged; it still hangs on the edge.

### Question

Is there a fool-proof way that I can use to calculate the scale such that there is an extra 30 days of padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your problem: `earliest` and `dateMin` point to the same object. Changing one will change the other:

```js
var earliest = new Date();
var dateMin = earliest;
dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getMonth() - 30);
console.log(earliest);
```

This, of course, has nothing to do with D3, this is a JavaScript feature. However, D3 provides a method which is not only easier but also avoids such mistakes.

#### A D3 fool-proof way:

You should use [`interval.offset`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_offset), which:

> Returns a new date equal to date plus step intervals.

For instance, adding 30 days:

```js
const date = new Date();
const datePlus30Days = d3.timeDay.offset(date, 30);
console.log(datePlus30Days)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, removing 30 days:

```js
const date = new Date();
const dateMinus30Days = d3.timeDay.offset(date, -30);
console.log(dateMinus30Days)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

So, in your scale, use:

```
var dateMin = d3.min(data, function(d){
    return d3.timeDay.offset(d.date, -30);
});

var dateMax = d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d3.timeDay.offset(d.date, 30);
});
```